# click on href without id or class cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm trying to click an href element using cypress I've wondered if I can access it by its content ex:

```
<a href=example.com>CONTENT</a>
```

but I couldn't find anything online.

I've tried using something like that:

```
cy.get('a[href*="url"]').click()
```

but it  also didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `contains` to select elements by textual content, like this:

```
cy.get('a').contains('CONTENT').click();
```

Note that the used `href` attribute value is invalid, protocol and quotes are missing, should be something like this:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/">CONTENT</a>
```

Documentation can be found here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contains` with selector and text something like:

```js
cy.contains('a', 'CONTENT').click()
```